# Importing data(i.e. a table) from another tab but still maintaining filter functionality

Tags: google-sheets

I'm experimenting with a sheet for work. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K8QhVKWSsvHTFKDHNv3ySb5bcaU9I7tczIZvIkegbw0/edit#gid=1582815105

Basically each of our staff will have one tab then I want to accumulate all of the tables from their tabs as one table on the mastersheet.

I'm having trouble getting the mastersheet to work because it seems the =importrange function doesn't to work if there's something in the way
(Error: Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in A5.)
The staff's tables are likely to increase in size.

Is there a way for it to automatically push the data down?

In the end, I hope to be able to be able to use filters on the mastersheet too; Will this screw up my =importrange too?

I'm quite a basic user to sorry if this is obvious but if anyone could be kind enough to point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful!!

If anything needs clarifying please let me know. 
Sheet is editable so feel free to work any magic necessary!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Importrange is only needed when you import from other spreadsheets. In your case you can use a literal array to gather all the separate sheets(tabs)..

```
=query({Sanshiro!A1:O; Suil!A1:O; Yujiro!A1:O;Josh!A1:O}, "select * where Col1 is not null")
```

(Formula added in sheet7, cell A1)
The query can be used to filter.

See if that works ?

Comment: Thank you JPV! 
That works great! It really is helping me understand more complicated formulae too.

Now all I need to solve is when sorting the masterlist, I get blank rows if the cell with the formula is not at the top of the list..

I wonder how I can delete the empty cells automatically with a live script..

Comment: Unless there is a way to use the formula you kindly provided, and have it past into a different cell, that way it won't be affected by using a filter for the table?

Comment: I'm not sure want if I understand correctly, but if you want to sort the columns after importing with the formula, make sure to use the formula in A1 (and freeze row 1) and make sure to also import the header rows. See formula in A1 of the copy sheet. Now try sorting (by clicking the arrows in next to (he column names A, B,...). Is that what you mean ?

Comment: Hi JPV, thanks again for your help.
Yes I'd like to be able to use filters from the top row. 

I see maybe you or someone (or even me I forget!) has tried what you suggest in putting the formula at in the top row and freezing it. 

Only thing is sorting bounces back to original data as I guess the formula is still live.